# Unresolved reference: javafx for Kotlin & Gradle on Github

Tags: kotlin, gradle, javafx, github-actions

I am working on a project with kotlin & gradle. It is hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/Orchaldir/KotlinFantasyWorld) and uses its actions for CI.

Last week it stopped compiling on github with the following problems:

```
e: /home/runner/work/KotlinFantasyWorld/KotlinFantasyWorld/src/main/kotlin/util/rendering/CanvasRenderer.kt: (7, 8): Unresolved reference: javafx
e: /home/runner/work/KotlinFantasyWorld/KotlinFantasyWorld/src/main/kotlin/util/rendering/CanvasRenderer.kt: (10, 34): Unresolved reference: GraphicsContext
e: /home/runner/work/KotlinFantasyWorld/KotlinFantasyWorld/src/main/kotlin/util/rendering/CanvasRenderer.kt: (23, 34): Unresolved reference: Color
```

See [here](https://github.com/Orchaldir/KotlinFantasyWorld/runs/597495105) for the full log.

It still works fine in Intellij.

I am pretty new with gradle. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to look for: https://openjfx.io/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by:

- Increasing the java version for CI
- Using the javafxplugin in gradle

See [[Close #32] Use javafxplugin](https://github.com/Orchaldir/KotlinFantasyWorld/commit/4ec05574330ba2b452bad9b8db78b9e4ab203dbf)